# Сократить код JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Привет.

После нажатия на определённую кнопку открывается блок div с уникальным id. Код js получается большой, потому что повторяется функция. Можно как то уменьшить код?

```
document.querySelector('button.1').onclick = function() {
var ob = document.getElementById('div1');
if( ob.style.display=='block') { ob.style.display='none'; }
        else  { ob.style.display='block'; }
}
document.querySelector('button.2').onclick = function() {
var ob = document.getElementById('div2');
if( ob.style.display=='block') { ob.style.display='none'; }
        else  { ob.style.display='block'; }
}
document.querySelector('button.3').onclick = function() {
var ob = document.getElementById('div3');
if( ob.style.display=='block') { ob.style.display='none'; }
        else  { ob.style.display='block'; }
}
document.querySelector('#type').onclick = function() {
var ob = document.getElementById('hid1');
if( ob.style.display=='block') { ob.style.display='none'; }
        else  { ob.style.display='block'; }
}
document.querySelector('#type2').onclick = function() {
var ob = document.getElementById('hid2');
if( ob.style.display=='block') { ob.style.display='none'; }
        else  { ob.style.display='block'; }
}
```

Пробовал вот так:

```
document.querySelector('button.1','button.2','button.3','#type','#type2').onclick = function() {
        var ob = document.getElementById('div1','div2','div3','hid1','hid2');
        if( ob.style.display=='block') { ob.style.display='none'; }
                else  { ob.style.display='block'; }
        }
```

но почему-то работает только первый в списке селектор?

**HTML**

```
<button class="1"></button>
<div id="div1">блаблабла</div>

...

<span id="type"></span>
<div id="hid1">блаблабла</div>

...
```

**CSS**

```
стилей для элементов нет, скрипт js скрывает div1,div2,div3,hid1,hid2
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос еще ваш HTML и CSS

Comment: А функцию, которая на `onclick` вешается не пробовали отдельно вынести? Передаете параметр (`div_id`) по которому изменяете стили. Уже меньше было бы кода.

Comment: Функция onclick в скрипте, зачем её лепить в HTML для каждой кнопки. От этого код не уменьшиться!

Comment: Я не про кнопки говорил, функция используется одна и та же, оформите ее как нормальную функцию, а потом назначайте на `onclick` через цикл по массиву селекторов (если грубо, то как-то так `[1,2,3].forEach(function(x) { bind() })`). Можно и не выносить отдельно, а сразу в `forEach` вставлять, но мало ли где исходная функция может еще понадобиться

Comment: Я пробовал делать массив `var array = [ div1,div2,div3,hid1,hid2]` но функция `onclick` не работает. О forEach ничего не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделим сначала функцию, которая применяется к нашим элементам. Возьмем для примера первый биндинг вашего кода:

```
document.querySelector('button.1').onclick = function() {
var ob = document.getElementById('div1');
if( ob.style.display=='block') { ob.style.display='none'; }
        else  { ob.style.display='block'; }
}
```

Приведем его к следующему виду (обезличим код, вынеся из него реальные значения):

```
var action_element = 'button.1',
    target_element = 'div1';
document.querySelector(action_element).onclick = function() {
    var ob = document.getElementById(target_element);
    if (ob.style.display == 'block') {
        ob.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        ob.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Поскольку теперь в коде мы работаем не с реальными значениями, а с параметрами, то мы можем этот код обернуть в функцию:

```
function element_binding(action_element, target_element) {
    document.querySelector(action_element).onclick = function() {
        var ob = document.getElementById(target_element);
        if (ob.style.display == 'block') {
            ob.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            ob.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
var action_element = 'button.1',
    target_element = 'div1';
element_binding(action_element, target_element);
```

Биндинг можно провести и без использования лишних переменных:

```
element_binding('button.1', 'div1');
```

Аналогичным образом вызываем функцию для других параметров.

```
element_binding('button.1', 'div1');
element_binding('button.2', 'div2');
element_binding('button.3', 'div3');
element_binding('#type', 'hid1');
element_binding('#type2', 'hid2');
```

Итого полный (и исправленный) код выглядит так:

```js
(function() {

function element_binding(action_element, target_element) {
    var target_element_style = document.getElementById(target_element).style;
    target_element_style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector(action_element).onclick = function() {
        if (target_element_style.display == 'block') {
            target_element_style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            target_element_style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
element_binding('button.class1', 'div1');
element_binding('button.class2', 'div2');
element_binding('button.class3', 'div3');
element_binding('#type', 'hid1');
element_binding('#type2', 'hid2');

})();
```

```html
<button class="class1">BUTTON_1</button>
<div id="div1">div1</div>

<button class="class2">BUTTON_2</button>
<div id="div2">div2</div>

<button class="class3">BUTTON_3</button>
<div id="div3">div3</div>

<span id="type">SPAN_1</span>
<div id="hid1">hid1</div>

<span id="type2">SPAN_2</span>
<div id="hid2">hid2</div>
```

Конструкция вида

```
(function() {
...
})();
```

используется для того, чтобы не захламлять глобальное пространство. Т.е. все функции и переменные объявленные там не будут конфликтовать с вашими глобальными функциями/переменными.

Для классов использовал более "классные" имена, т.к. `class='1'` при поиске выдаст ошибку.

Дополнительно в момент инициализации задаю свойство `display: block`, т.к. иначе для того, чтобы скрыть/показать кнопку пришлось бы нажимать ее два раза.

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться - когда js программисты начнут от вложенных и безымянных функций отказываться? Раньше ещё могли оправдываться, что классов нет и ооп не работает, но сейчас же классы уже официально появились.. Только оправдание, что так в книгах пишут и на курсах учат я не принимаю, ведь есть сатанисты, которые тоже уверенны в своей вере и отступать не обираются.

Через пару лет Вас на работу с таким кодом не возьмут. И snake-case в js не используют, это аморально.

Comment: @shatal, я не js-программист, про классы я не знаю (они разве уже реализованы?). И вы правда думаете, что ТС с его знаниями JS сможет сразу же въехать во все это?

Comment: А ещё если кнопок будет несколько сотен ( клавиатура ), то в памяти будут висеть сотни экземпляров функции element_binding, т.к. хандлер замыкает в себе объекты верхней скопы.

Comment: Если ТС будут попадаться не js программисты, то он может и сума сойти, собирая в голове ненужную информацию. Вам так не кажется?

Comment: @shatal, вас же это не остановило ) И если вам так хочется пообщаться - добро пожаловать в [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) (либо можете создать собственный и пригласить туда)

Comment: @shatal, проверял, все работает (по крайней мере в хроме), если есть что по существу - пишите по существу, если поговорить охота - для этого чат есть.

Comment: @shatal, и вы видно не поняли смысл ответа. Автор не смог самостоятельно выделить функцию. Я по шагам расписал как и что получается. В вашем же ответе только код, никаких объяснений и смысл вашего ответа? Показать что вы знаете решение? Из-за таких как вы потом и ругают горе-разработчиков

Comment: Я и не пытался что-то понять, я показал как можно сократить. Ну а если кому-то не понятно "как работает цикл "или "как получить элемент из массива", то я просто не могу нести ответственность за это, которую на меня Вы пытаетесь переложить. Таким нужно идти читать доки, а не смотреть примеры с snace_case "потому-что я так умею и вообще я не js программист, а просто мне нефиг делать вот я и залез сюда".

Comment: @BOPOH цифры вместо символов - это для примера. Код js намного меньше Спасибо. Вот только строка `target_element_style.display = 'block';` лишняя  ...  дело в том что есть кнопки которые видно только на экране не больше w800px.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, можно использовать инлайновое навешивание событий ( если кнопки как у вас действительно разные, тут и дивы + кнопки с разными классами )

```
<button ... onclick='toggleVisible(".div1")' ></button>
<div ... onclick='toggleVisible("hid1")' ></div>
```

А вот всего одна функция

```
 var toggleVisible = function(target) {
    var el = document.querySelector(target);
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";     
 }
```